# Unit testing angular controllers along with respective templates

Tags: unit-testing, controller, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test my angular controller along with its template. But not finding a way to load template. Even I am compiling my template with controller's scope also I am unable to find elements in template.

My Controller:

```
    angular.module("myapp").controller("controller", ['$scope',  controller]);
        function controller($scope) {
    //Code
    }
```

Template:

```
    <html><body>
    <p id="test">This is test content</p>
    </body></html>
```

My test case:

```
    it("Testing ui elements", function(){

                var controller = createController();

                expect($scope.loading).toBeFalsy();

                var element = $compile(listTemplate)($scope);
                $scope.$digest();
                console.log(element.find('#test').html());
            });
```

OutPut:

```
    LOG: undefined
```

Comment: I believe the $compile function is only used for directives. What it sounds like you want is End to End testing. Check out Angualr Docs on that subject. [E2E Testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my create controller method as below.

```
createController = function() {
            var element = angular.element("<div id='controller' ng-controller='controller'></div>");
            element.append(listTemplate);
            $compile(element)($scope);
            angular.element('body').append(element);
            $scope = element.scope();
        };
```

Now I am able to get element by Id as $('#test').html();